# how to (integrate)call post API with 2 parameters and 1 PDF file in android java

Tags: java, android, api

How to attach PDF file to post API with two parameter? I am using Fast android networking library.

I am able to call API but I when user touched button my API called in my API have three parameters like this:

message = "Test"
receiver_Email = "@gmail.com"
File = text.PDF;

Sy API allows only PDF form met with message and email. I am using Fast android networking library. I try to call API but I am not able to do it.

I also looked at some examples but it couldn't help me out.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

just call this method from your onCreate  this is the easy way to call API with file and parameter I hope it helps you

//method used  to call API to send email

```
enter code here
@RequiresApi(API = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
public void call_Api()
{

    final String key = "file";
    final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "/test.pdf");

    AndroidNetworking.initialize(this);
    AndroidNetworking.upload("your API")
            .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
            .addMultipartParameter("message", "test")
            .addMultipartParameter("receiverEmail","testrg0017@gmail.com")
            .addMultipartFile(key, file)
            .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
            .build()
            .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
                {

                    Log.d("res ",response.toString());
                    if(file.exists())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(PdfGeneration.this, "API call successfully",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
                @Override
                public void onError(ANError anError)
                {

                    anError.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("res12 ",anError.toString());
                    if(!file.exists())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(PdfGeneration.this, "file not available",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }

            });

}
```